# how to sort divs by date in data-date

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#selsort').change(function(){
if ($(this).val() == 'asc') {/*sort abc by date asc;*/}
else {/*sort abc by date desc;*/}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='abc' data-date='21.09.2018'>lorem 1</div>
<div class='abc' data-date='22.09.2018'>lorem 2</div>
<div class='abc' data-date='23.09.2018'>lorem 3</div>

<select id='selsort'>
<option value='asc'>ASC</option>
<option value='desc'>DESC</option>
</select>
```

How to sort `abc` divs by date in `date-date`?

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
function dateFromElement($element) {
  return new Date($element.data('date').split('.').reverse().join('-'));
}

$('#selsort').on('change', function() {
    $('[data-date]')
      .sort((date1El, date2El) => $(this).val() === 'asc'
        ? dateFromElement($(date1El)) - dateFromElement($(date2El))
        : dateFromElement($(date2El)) - dateFromElement($(date1El)))
      .appendTo($('[data-wrapper]'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-wrapper>
  <div class='abc' data-date='21.09.2018'>lorem 1</div>
  <div class='abc' data-date='22.09.2018'>lorem 2</div>
  <div class='abc' data-date='23.09.2018'>lorem 3</div>
</div>

<select id='selsort'>
  <option value='asc'>ASC</option>
  <option value='desc'>DESC</option>
</select>
```

**Note**: jQuery's `sort` method is apparently only intended for internal use. You can easily transform the selection into an array and use `Array.sort` itself if need be (jQuery's version is a proxy of it, but might just disappear in the future I guess).

Comment: it works thanks. I suppose this should be a simple function in the future. Like $('.abc').sort(attr('data-date'), desc);`